# topologically equivalent spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I was wondering if there exist a metric $d:X\times X\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (with $X:=(-1,1)$) such that $(-1,1)$ is complete and that $(d,X)$, $(d_{usual},X)$ are topologically equivalent?

I know for example that $(-1,1)\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a homeomorphism, because we can find a one-to-one function $f$ such that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ is continuous. So we can conclude that $(-1,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphic. But what about $(d,X)$ and $(d_{usual},X)$?

Comment: Just pull back the metric on $\mathbb{R}$ along the homeomorphism.

Comment: please rewrite your statement "(−1,1)⟶R is a homeomorphism".. you have not given any map so, it would be better to write "as $(-1,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphic"....

Comment: completeness is not a topological property :-o

Comment: @SenoreBunuel That's kind of the point of the question. You can have homeomorphic spaces, one which has a complete metric topology and the other with a non-complete metric topology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any homeomorphism $f : (-1, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$ yields a complete metric for $(-1, 1)$, because $\mathbb{R}$ is complete. Just put $d(x_0, x_1) = d(f(x_0), f(x_1))$. Note that $d$ is obviously symmetric and satisfies the triangle inequality. The only point where you need to use the fact that $f$ is a bijection is to show that $d(x_0, x_1) = 0$ implies $x_0 = x_1$; and to show that $d$ is topologically equivalent to the standard metric on $(-1, 1)$, you need to use the fact that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: But completeness is not topological property which may not be preserved under homeomorphism formexample $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphic but they  $(0,1)$ is not complete!..may be i do not undertand the question :(

Comment: @SenoreBunuel $(0,1)$ with the usual metric is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ but not isometric (hence is not complete). However, $(0,1)$ with the metric Zhen Lin has given is both homeomorphic **and** isometric to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @DanielRust The statement in parenthesis is a bit too strong.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz True, I should have said "hence is not necessarily complete".